# How to make sure a POST request to a REST api is "safe"

Tags: node.js, security, rest, express

I have a JSON REST-api with NodeJs, Express and MongoDB. 
Several user accounts are using this API to CRUD resources of a web app.
Access to the API is granted via a /login route, where users can establish a session.

But lets say one of my users are evil, and he knows that the front-end is talking to a API, and he wants to send some unexpected JSON data to the API.

Lets say he establish a session with the API, and then use a REST-client, like POSTMAN to send JSON that is not expected to a POST route.

What is the route is expecting something like this

```
{
  name: "Anders",
  age: 32, 
  country: "sweden"
}
```

but instead receive something like this from an "evil" user armed with a REST-client.

```
{
  wrong_key1: 23423432423423,
  wrong_key2: 2341234123431542315413, 
  wrong_key2: ["ascdaeawe", "sadfasfe", "sdfahrta"]
  wrong_key4: "http://www.evildomain.com/",
}
```

What is the best way to handle this?

1. **Filter out just the expected values from req.body**, validate them, and ignore all others?
2. **Disallow request from other domains**, making sure the request are only coming from my web app domain? This seems a bit "anti REST"
   although, and I dont even know if this is possible.
3. **Expect users with a login never to do something like this**, and therefore not deal with it?
4. Something else...?

Comment: Use a json validator -- something like [joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) from the `hapi` suite or [jsonschema](https://github.com/tdegrunt/jsonschema)?  These will do most of the lifting for you so you can focus on what to do when an error or bad data is encountered.

Comment: json itself is considered safe. you should always validate user-submitted data, no matter what flavor. submitted data should, as much as possible, trigger remote control actions, not directly invoke those actions.

Comment: @dandavis: I know I should validate the input. But up to now I have built small custom validations performed on the keys I EXPECT to get... like 'name', 'age' and 'country'. The problem above rose when I realized someone can actually send a completely different JSON, with different structure and keys.

Comment: if that problem arose, you were not doing the validation thoroughly in the first place. your app should be un-aware of stuff it's not expecting, and "bonus data" should have no effect at all. you should be looking for what you need from the submit, and validating that what you need is correct.